# Options for connecting Business Basic to Windows environment

Tags: c#, .net, aix, basic, bbj

I'm looking for options for connecting to (primarily reading data) UNIX/AIX/Business Basic from Windows systems.
I program in C# mostly so would need a .NET solution.

Solutions or comments are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends upon which Business Basic compiler you are using. the most common is BBx, so I will answer your question based upon this particular compiler. BBx will run seamless on Windows or Unix platforms. You can interchange programs between them without recompiling them. BUT, you must have a compiler to make it run. Remember that BBx, ProvideX, Thorobred basic, etc are all M-code compilers, and not P-code compilers. Most people use the utility program that comes with BBx to interchange data between the BBx environment and a web site. Go find the BBx manuals that come with the compiler. You can also use an OPTIONAL ODBC driver. Call Basis International In New Mexico for the driver. Later versions of BBx can also read/write to SQL databases and other types of file systems. But, most BBx programmers will use the keyed file system that comes with it. You can also read/write to ascii files in BBx.

Please note: BBx and all other Business Basic compilers do NOT use flat ascii files. They can write flat ascii files, but, in my 30 years I have never seen anyone use them as a file structure. They are only used to import/export data to/from BBx. The keyed files have a SIT area, Keyed Area, and a Data area. You NEED to read these files in BBx. If you use C or some other language to alter the data in the file, you corrupt the Checksum and the file will become useless. And, you will have one very pissed off customer.

You might also consider getting a BBx compiler for your Windows environment to help you. Pretty cheap option if you don't have source code on BBx side. Remember this ISN'T Basic...it's Business Basic.

You should also find the data structures of the file system on the BBx side. It is very hard to work with the system without it. Some programs will have DBMS on-board, and you can just print out the record layouts to the hundreds of files on the system.

Comment: Thanks for the completeness of your response. I am using a COM component called dserve2.dll to read from the system. I have no real need (or desire) to write to the system.  Frankly, the sooner it dies and goes away the better as far as I'm concerned. I'm sure it's a fine system but for a small company like ours it seems like a simpler product (SQL Server) would make my life much easier.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends a lot on the format that is used to store your data. If the data is just flat files, you could use something like rcp or ftp. A number of .NET componentens, both commercial and open-source are available for this kind of access.

If not, you can look for ODBC drivers. There are  some vendors that sell drivers for BBX, C-ISAM, D-ISAM, etc..

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mike, the easiest way would be to use an ODBC. you can find one on the basis web site www.basis.com (they are bbx creators).

If you want fast on the fly access to the data you would be better of writing your own back-end in bbx and have it talk to you C# program using sockets.

I have written an Internet banking app (ASP.NET) talking to a bbx host in this way.

If you need further help feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

BBX does has a MS-Dos version. With this you can fully approach all the databases in MS-Dos. With a tool DOSbox you can emulate ms-dos for windows 7 8 and 10.

Within windows you have to assign a windows driveletter to the network and location of your Unix database. 
Within BBX it's possible to mount this drive.